# How do I incorporate .net IServiceCollection with Ninject dependency injection?

Tags: .net, ninject

I have a .net 4.8 framework web api application using ninject for DI and I'm trying to include a .net standard 2.0 library that includes a few ServiceCollection extensions for dependency injection. Is there a way to mix these DI frameworks?